# How to run <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] in a react app, and what will happen when deployed?

Tags: php, reactjs, localization, geolocation

I would like to run a php script like below to get the user's language on their device
when they access my website which is a React application.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
```

I am tempted to use browswer's global object like below but apparently it is not reliable
and could get the wrong language/country code which I do not want for this app since
localization is a high priority.

```
navigator.language
```

I have no idea of how PHP works and if I later deploy it, will this work with my React app that currently is set up with Firebase which I will also use for deployment.

If it does work, how can I implement the PHP code above so I can get the user's lang/country code...

Comment: One of the ways: send an AJAX request using ReactJS to your server and use the response from PHP

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP file - name it as you like, ie. getLanguage.php and store in root folder of your website.

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    echo json_encode(['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']]);
?>
```

Then you can access it via AJAX call or even in a browser by simply requesting: https://yourdomain.com/getLanguage.php and you get JSON response like this:

`{"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE":"en-US,pl;q=0.5"}`

working example: https://allegronauta.pl/tests/getLanguage.php

Comment: i stored it in my react app folder at the same level as package.json and it says not found.... don't i need to have a php server running to be able to see it? i don;t know how php works, can you show me ajax call as i am not familiar

Comment: yes, of course you have to have some PHP-capable server running somewhere. for testing purposes you can use mine at https://allegronauta.pl/tests/getLanguage.php but for production you should have your own. How/where do you deploy your app?

Comment: that is the trouble, i am using Firebase for backend and will be using Firebase deployment. I have no idea how I would be able to have a php-server and react running at the same time... but it is very easy to deploy on Fireabse deploy

Comment: As far as I know Firebase doesn't support any user code running locally. I think Google Cloud allows it (https://www.google.com/search?q=google+cloud+deploy+php+script) but never tried. For the time being you can use the service I set up for you. But if you plan to use it as "production" I have to add some authentication to prevent misuse :-)

Comment: ok, i made this ajax call to the php file in my root folder $.ajax({
    url: '../getLanguage.php',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data); // will print "message"
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log('error');
    }.bind(this)
    }); it returns not found 404 error

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/getLanguage.php 404 (Not Found), it is pointing at the right location...

Comment: you won't get this running that way. node.js webserver doesn't support php by default. you need some additional server like Apache (ie. bundled within XAMPP package) to run it locally. But if you plan to deploy it as an React app you need some PHP capable server on the internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246926/discussion-between-dink74-and-masafood).